# How to scroll to a section without rows in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autoscroll

Yes, there are many similar/equal questions, but none worked for me.

I've a `UITableView` with some sections. The rows of these sections are created conform user put information in the table, so I want to auto-scroll when user type a especific field, but I don't know which `IndexPath` I must use to use the function:

`UITableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true )`

The problem is that I've section without rows, so I can't use the function above without especific a row in `IndexPath`. (In this case, the section without rows is the 3rd).

I already tried this:

```
let sectionRect : CGRect = tableViewOrder.rect(forSection: 3)
tableViewOrder.scrollRectToVisible(sectionRect, animated: true)
```

and

```
tableViewOrder.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: 3), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
```

Both not works.

Comment: Do you have a static or dynamic table cell ??

Comment: Is dynamic, added as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
tableViewOrder.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0,y: tableViewOrder.contentSize.height - tableViewOrder.frame.height)
```

Comment: `tableViewOrder.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: tableViewOrder.numberOfRows(inSection: 2)-1, section: 2), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)` => Not works

Comment: try **tableViewOrder.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0 section:4), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)**

Comment: segmentation occurs when complicating  the statement see edit

Comment: This is exactly that I commented at first line.

Comment: which the difference between `contentSize` and `frame` ?

Comment: **contentSize** is the scrollable content size of the table (sum height for all cells ) , frame is the visual height

Comment: Thanks. I had no cells but only table header view. Other methods didn't work, but this works in my case.